# Remove while iterating std::vector (indirectly)

Tags: c++, vector

This question has been asked multiple times but mine is a slightly different case. Say I have a std::vector of observers which I notify when a certain event happens:

```
void SomeClass::doThing() {
    // do things ...
    // notify observers
    for (auto* o : mObservers) {
        o->thingHappened();
    }
}
```

What if in the implementation of `thingHappened` the observer calls a method in `SomeClass` to remove itself from the observers? What are some of the best ways to handle this?

One possibility is to make a copy of `mObservers` before the for loop and use it instead, but the extra copy can be wasteful.

Another possibility is to delegate changes to the array to be run after the loop is finished, perhaps setting a lock (just a boolean) before the loop starts and while this lock is set, the methods that mutate the vector delegate themselves to be called after the loop is done when lock is set to false (could be done with a vector of lambdas... quite cumbersome).

Comment: You've already described the only 2 ways I can think of for handling this situation. Are you hoping there's a 3rd?

Comment: @MarkRansom yes

Comment: @xissburg How expensive is it to copy an `observer`? Because if it's trivial or cheap, then the copy is definitely worth it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it's a vector of pointers

Comment: @xissburg That's a relatively cheap copy, then. There's no problem just making a copy of it.

Comment: @Xirema yeah, probably...

Comment: How many observers are we talking about? If it is not a lot you can use a `std::list` and get around the problem pretty easily.

Comment: @NathanOliver hmm yeah, might be a good choice in this case since there's no advantage really in having the contents of the array to be contiguous in memory...

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think you can remove an element from a `list` without causing undefined behavior when you later try to increment the iterator to that element.

Comment: @MarkRansom You can't but you can get the next iterator first.  I'm writing up an answer.

Comment: I'm with @Rakete1111 here: performance cost of the copy should be negligible, both in term of speed and in terms of memory used. copying a vector of n elements will likely take much less time than calling a function on the n elements. Measure time taken for the copy: if it's actually negligible, go for the easier and cleaner code: copy the vector and forget about the prolem "the function called can invalidate the iterator I'm working with". Easier to write (and maintain) more than all other method suggested

Answer (score 7):

If you have control over the signature of `thingHappened()`, you can change it to return a `bool` indicating whether it should be removed. Then, you can remove all the values which return `true` (or `false`; depends on the semantics you want).

Luckily for us, [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) are guaranteed to call the predicate exactly once per object in the range.

```
void SomeClass::doThing() {
    // do things ...
    // notify observers
    auto newEnd = std::remove_if(mObservers.begin(), mObservers.end(), [](auto *o) {
        return o->thingHappened();
    });
    // assuming mObservers is a vector
    mObservers.erase(newEnd, mObservers.end());
}
```

Comment: I think I should change the title of this question. It's not only about removal, it's about any mutation to the vector. Possibly multiple mutations.

Comment: @xissburg That would be a separate question

Answer (score 5):

One way to work around this is to change the data structure.  With a `std::list` the removal of a element only invalidates iterators/references/pointers to that element.  Since the rest of the list remains intact all we need to do is get an iterator to the next element before we process the current one.  That would look like

```
for (auto it = the_list.begin(); it != the_list.end();)
{
    auto next = std::next(it);
    it->call_the_possibly_removing_function();
    it = next;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Now the only way this could fail is if an *unrelated* observer is removed from the list, and that observer happens to be the one that `next` is pointing to.

Comment: @Xirema It could happen in non-multithreaded code: if one observer has a reference to another, it could call a member function to remove the other

Comment: @Xirema Justin is correct. I've actually worked on code like that, it was a real pain to get working properly. Hopefully it's not a common situation.

Answer (score 3):

> What if in the implementation of thingHappened the observer calls a method in SomeClass to remove itself from the observers? What are some of the best ways to handle this?

The following method has worked for me in the past.

1. Note that your are going to iterate over the observers.
2. When a client requests to remove an observer to be removed, check whether you are in the middle of iterating over the observers. If you are, set it aside in another vector. If not, remove it from the observers.
3. After you are done iterating over the observers, remove all the observers that need to be removed.
4. Note that you are done iterating over the observers.

---

```
void SomeClass::removeObserver(Observer* o) {
   if ( this->isIterating  )
   {
      observersToRemove.push_back(o);
   }
   else
   {
      // Code for real removal of the observer
   }
}

void SomeClass::doThing() {
   this->isIterating = true;
   for (auto* o : mObservers) {
      o->thingHappened();
   }

   for ( auto* o : observersToRemove )
   {
      // Code for real removal of the observer
   }

   observersToRemove.clear();

   this->isIterating = false;
}
```

Comment: My main problem with this approach is that there are a lot more variables floating around, but the extra flexibility might make this worthwhile. It may be possible to wrap much of this inside a single object in a way that makes it easier to keep track of what's happening

Comment: @Justin, as you can see from three different answers, they are more than one ways to solve the problem. Use the approach that you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: I like this approach to some degree but it really is more complicated. Plus something that might be a problem is that changes performed during the iteration are not immediately visible. If there's a method to check if an object is an observer, the observer could remove itself in its implementation of `thingHappened` but it would still be inside the list of observers, so if it calls `isObserving` it would return true.

Comment: @Justin, yes, it does make the other functions a bit more complicated but you have all the data necessary to correctly implement `isObserving`. You have to check whether the input is in `mObservers` first. If it is there, you'll need to check whether it is in `observersToRemove`.

Comment: @xissburg you could simplify this approach. Rather than doing two different things based on a flag, simply *always* add the observer you want to remove to a second list. Then just before your `for` loop, remove all observers in that list and empty the list.

Comment: @MarkRansom, the only problem with that would be that the observer won't be removed from `mObservers` even when `removeObserver` is called while not iterating over `mObservers`.

Comment: @RSahu I'm making the assumption that the contents of `mObservers` is only relevant in the `for` loop, and no harm is done by delaying the removal. I realize it's a big assumption.

Answer (score 2):

[R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152850/1896169) provides a flexible technique for solving this problem. The one thing that concerns me about it is the introduction of several variables that you have to manage. However, it's totally possible to wrap the functionality in a utility class.

Here's a sketch of what you could do:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// Note that this is not threadsafe
template <typename Type>
class MutableLock {
    bool locked = false;
    Type value;
    // std::function gives us a more general action,
    // but it does come at a cost; you might want to consider using
    // other techniques.
    std::vector<std::function<void(Type&)>> actions;

public:
    class AutoLocker {
        MutableLock& lock;

        friend class MutableLock<Type>;

        explicit AutoLocker(MutableLock& lock)
            : lock{ lock }
        {
        }

    public:
        ~AutoLocker()
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    };

    MutableLock() = default;

    // The [[nodiscard]] is a C++17 attribute that
    // would help enforce using this function appropriately
    [[nodiscard]] AutoLocker lock()
    {
        locked = true;
        return AutoLocker{ *this };
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        for (auto const& action : actions) {
            action(value);
        }
        actions.clear();

        locked = false;
    }

    template <typename F>
    void action(F&& f)
    {
        if (!locked) {
            f(value);
        } else {
            actions.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(f));
        }
    }

    // There needs to be some way to expose the value
    // not under the lock (so that we can use it when
    // we call `lock()`).
    //
    // Even if your `Type` is not a range, this would
    // be fine, as member functions of a template class
    // aren't instantiated unless you call them.
    //
    // However, you may want to expose other ways to
    // access the value
    auto begin() { return std::begin(value); }
    auto end() { return std::end(value); }
    auto begin() const { return std::begin(value); }
    auto end() const { return std::end(value); }
};
```

Using it would look something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Observer {
public:
    virtual void thingHappened() = 0;

protected:
    ~Observer() = default;
};

class SomeClass {
    MutableLock<std::vector<Observer*>> observers;

public:
    void addObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        observers.action([observer](auto& observers) {
            observers.push_back(observer);
        });
    }

    void remove(Observer const* observer)
    {
        observers.action([observer](auto& observers) {
            observers.erase(std::remove(observers.begin(), observers.end(), observer), observers.end());
        });
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        auto lock = observers.lock();
        for (auto* observer : observers) {
            observer->thingHappened();
        }
        // when `lock` goes out of scope, we automatically unlock `observers` and
        // apply any actions that were built up
    }
};

class Observer1 : public Observer {
public:
    SomeClass* thing;

    void thingHappened() override
    {
        std::cout << "thing 1\n";
        thing->remove(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass thing;
    Observer1 obs;
    obs.thing = &thing;

    thing.addObserver(&obs);
    thing.doSomething();
    thing.doSomething();
}
```

<sup>[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc909d74c6f6d5af)</sup>